# SSR selection - how is on resistance related to output IV curve?

Tags: opto-isolator, solid-state-relay, component-selection, ratings

I am looking at the datasheet at the link below, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am missing.
http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/TLP3542(F)/TLP3542F-ND/871299

This is a Toshiba SSR whose on resistance is 100mΩ maximum. There is an on-state I-V curve that shows a current of 0.5A at 25V, implying an on resistance of 50Ω! The problem is, I'm looking for at least 2mA output at 12VDC, and based on that IV plot, I won't be getting it.

I am clearly misunderstanding something here. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo- Von should be mV, not volts.

Even so, there are small discrepancies between the typical on resistance, the curve you mention, and the Ron-Ta curve at 2A, but not enough to get excited about.

Comment: OK, that sounds about right. The rest of the datasheet is riddled with typos, and the part is only meant to be able to break 60V.

Thanks!